# Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a submission form that consist of a DropDownList Control; it's ListItem values consist of an UniqueIdentifier, e.g. 524988aa-0594-4ebe-b7fa-61396855e17f.

I'm attempting to insert the value of the ListItem into a table in the database via a stored procedure, but get a "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid" error upon submission.

Hypertext:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlserver" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Server 1" Value="88dc9e7d-0904-4a49-a6d9-8d0badfc4d0b" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Server 2" Value="524988aa-0594-4ebe-b7fa-61396855e17f" />
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "InsertClient";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = ddlserver.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPhone.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServicesNum", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = rbzero.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;
```

stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertClient]

    @UserId UniqueIdentifier,
    @ClientName nvarchar(150),
    @EmailAddress nvarchar(150),
    @PhoneNumber nvarchar(50),
    @ServicesNum nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO  Client_tb (UserId, ClientName, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, ServicesNum)
    VALUES (@UserId, @ClientName,  @EmailAddress, @PhoneNumber, @ServicesNum) 
END
```

...could I get some assistance please as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your issue is, `@UserId` is defined as a `UniqueIdentifier` and you are trying to pass in a string. Convert the string to a new `Guid()` object, then assign that Guid object as the `.Value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's this line here:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = ddlserver.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

You are saying it's a `Guid` (or UniqueIdentifier, different names for the same thing) and passing in a `String` (because of the `ToString()`, although it was already a String anyway).

Change it to pass a `Guid` like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(ddlserver.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(ddlserver.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't *cast* a string to a GUID. You need to use the appropriate overload of `Guid.Parse()` or `Guid.TryParse()` to get what you want.

Comment: Or just `new Guid(string)`

Answer (score 0):

`ddlserver.SelectedValue.ToString();` Is obviously a string
You assign it as a guid parameter: `.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)`
Cast to guid with: `new Guid(ddlserver.SelectedValue.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely occurring in this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = ddlserver.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Try explicitly creating a GUID like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new System.Guid(ddlserver.SelectedValue.ToString());
```